# Using locks instead of events?

Tags: python, multithreading, events, locking, python-multithreading

So I was learning about threads, and saw that locks were used for synchronizing threads. However, I don't understand why it would be more advantageous to use of lock instead of triggering an event.

This is a sample where I made the first thread finish **after** the second by triggering an event. Is there a way to use locks to achieve the same result, and is it more efficient?

```
from threading import *
import time

list1 = []
def computation():
    print('Starting computation')
    global list1
    for x in range(100000000):
        list1.append(x) 
    if t2 == True:                     #Making it give me a "result" after the other thread if it would need data from it, for example.
        print('End of computation')

def Background_work(x, lock):
    with lock:
        for x in range(x):
            print('...')
            time.sleep(2)
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    t1 = Thread(target = computation)
    t2 = Thread(target = Background_work, args = (5, lock))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    print('All tasks completed')
```

I also included a useless lock in `Background_work()` because I didn't understand why this code didn't give the same result:

```
list1 = []
def computation():
    print('Starting computation')
    global list1
    for x in range(100000000):
        list1.append(x) 
        time.sleep(0.01)
    print('End of computation')

def Background_work(x, lock):
    with lock:
        for x in range(x):
            print('...')
            time.sleep(2)



t1 = Thread(target = computation)
t2 = Thread(target = Background_work, args = (5, lock))
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

I thought that the first thread would run until it reached `time.sleep()` at which point the lock for the second thread would make it wait until itself finished since the first thread is sleeping.

Comment: What are your examples trying to accomplish. It appears that you are simply forcing t2 to wait a while for t1 to finish. t1 appends to List1 but t2 does not access List1. Locks are commonly used to prevent inappropriate simultaneous access to a shared object.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps my example wasn't the best to illustrate that since I don't actually use any data from the second thread, but these are just filler examples. I included a comment saying that a probable situation would be for it to use data from the second thread.

Comment: I think you are mistaken in what `t2 == True` does. That `True` is not `t2`'s return value. `t1` is completing after `t2` because it takes longer. An effect that is exacerbated by the GIL (`t1` runs a bit, then `t2`, which .sleeps and releases the GIL, then `t1` runs another bit...) If you make your range smaller (remove one or two zeroes) you'll see that `t1` finishes earlier. Also, I'd invite you to transform your two functions to do the same `.appending` to a list and see the huge performance difference between using threads vs. using processes.

Comment: I understand better thanks to your comment, but I still have some uncertainties. Why does t1 stop running if there's nothing to make it go to sleep? And if 1 thread has to go to sleep for another to work, is the point of multithreading only for another thread to work while one waits (like while it's contacting a server)? Yes, I realized you're right, the return value of t2 is not True. I will also try what you said in the end. I'm also curious to know why the lock I used didn't change anything.

Comment: Threads create the illusion of simultaneous execution by rapidly switching back and forth periodically.  The switching is not under your direct control.  The purpose of a Lock is to prevent two threads from "simultaneously" trying to modify the same data structure.  One thread can take ownership of the Lock, which prevents other threads from getting control of the same Lock.  In your test code you only use the Lock in one thread; this will not do anything at all.

Comment: A thread does not have to execute a time.sleep call in order to let other threads run.  They each run independently.  The OS switches back and forth continuously, in effect making it look as if all the threads are running at once.  In reality the threads are taking turns on a single CPU core.